# upload image to server and saving url to server

Tags: php, sql, upload

I am building an image uploader, by which I would like to upload my image to the server and replacing the old image URL in the database with the new one.  The upload part is working perfectly, however I am unable get the imageURL in the database.  Can someone take a look at my code please and tell me where I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$target_dir = "media/images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOK = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
 if(isset($_POST["uploadImage"])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
      if ($check != false) {
         echo "File is an image - " .$check["mime"]. ".";
       $uploadOK = 1;
      } else {
         echo "File not an image";
         $uploadOK = 0;
     }
 }

 // check if file exists 
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   echo "sorry File exists";
      $uploadOK = 0;
 }

  // check fle size
  if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
     echo "Sorry your file is too large.";
    $uploadOK = 0;
 }

 // Allow certain file formats
 if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" &&     $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
 echo "sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF files allowed.";
 $uploadOK == 0;
}

// check if $uploadOK is set 0 by an error
 if ($uploadOK == 0) {
     echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded.";
     // if everything is ok try to upload file
  } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  $target_file)) {
     echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has      been uploaded.";
     include 'connect.php';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO image(name,imageURL, image_cat_id, AlbumID) VALUES (home1, ?, 8, 0)");

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $target_file);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
 } else {
     echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
 }

 }
 ?>
```

Result on successful upload:

> File is an image - image/png.The file arrowdown_51.png has been uploaded.
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\Mosta Dynamic\CMS\upload.php on line 47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, that the function prepare() returns a boolean value ... I guess, that you made a mistake in the SQL-Query. Try it with the following:

```
INSERT INTO image(name,imageURL, image_cat_id, AlbumID)
VALUES ('home1', ?, '8', '0')
```

EDIT: If the above query also not persists the records: check also, if the names of your columns (and the table) are correct.

Please excuse my bad english, I'm not a native speaker ... :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply - have tried your solution and the error is gone, however the database is not updating.